# Why does the boot process keep referencing the drive/partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab, drive

I recently replaced two 1-terabyte hard drives with a single 4-terabyte hard drive.

To make sure the new drive would work redundantly, I tested out the `nofail` option (see the `fstab` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for details). I would turn the system off, unplug the drive, and see if the system still booted. Somewhere during my testing, I experienced freezes during boot. Once I did manage to boot, the system hanged up after going to the lock screen.

Things seem to be stable now. I took a look at the logs using [`journalctl`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/journalctl.1.en.html), but I'm not sure what to look for and the program puts out hundreds of lines information.

Than I tried `sudo cat /var/log/boot.log`, and ended up with this:

```
[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…35\x2d43a7\[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…5\x2d43a7\x[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…5\x2d43a7\x[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…2d43a7\x2d9[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[     *] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[    **] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[   ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[  *** ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[ ***  ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[***   ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[*     ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d…d43a7\x2d9a[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-168dfcf7\x2d7635\x2d43a7\x2d9a22\x2dcce4598b8844.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/168dfcf7-7635-43a7-9a22-cce4598b8844.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/media2.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
[  OK  ] Reached target Bluetooth.
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
         Starting Set console scheme...
[  OK  ] Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
[  OK  ] Closed Syslog Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting AppArmor initialization...
[  OK  ] Started Emergency Shell.
[  OK  ] Reached target Emergency Mode.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Started Set console font and keymap.
[  OK  ] Started Set console scheme.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[  OK  ] Started Network Name Resolution.
[  OK  ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[  OK  ] Started AppArmor initialization.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[  OK  ] Started Raise network interfaces.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
```

When I run that command again, I get the same output sans the repeating portion of the first line.
The UUID (`168dfcf7-7635-43a7-9a22-cce4598b8844`) is for the only partition on one of the replaced hard drives. It's actually still present - though commented out - in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=766c6a6f-98fc-4c26-868c-c2d542ad373a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4DD5-F9C6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=09724afe-6b53-4b29-afb8-0760ed0a1b01 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

#UUID=3fe702f9-bf22-4690-99c4-d7dc5be8079b  /mnt/media  ext4    defaults    0   2
#UUID=168dfcf7-7635-43a7-9a22-cce4598b8844  /mnt/media2 ext4    defaults    0   2
UUID=41aed6f4-8336-48ef-95d0-9911d81e9f75   /mnt/vault  ext4    defaults,nofail 0   2
```

**Why is the boot process referencing that drive/partition?** Did I not remove it properly from the system? I assumed commenting it out of the `/etc/fstab` file would be enough? Is this linked to the system instability I had when testing out the larger hard drive?

*NOTE:* The operating system is installed on a separate solid-state drive.

Here's what the output from `sudo lsblk -f` looks like:

```
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashf                                                /snap/gnome-logs/4
loop1  squashf                                                /snap/gnome-calcul
loop2  squashf                                                /snap/gnome-system
loop3  squashf                                                /snap/gnome-calcul
loop4  squashf                                                /snap/gnome-3-26-1
loop5  squashf                                                /snap/gnome-logs/6
loop6  squashf                                                /snap/gtk-common-t
loop7  squashf                                                /snap/core/7270
loop8  squashf                                                /snap/gnome-3-28-1
loop9  squashf                                                /snap/core/7396
loop10 squashf                                                /snap/gnome-charac
loop11 squashf                                                /snap/gtk-common-t
loop12 squashf                                                /snap/gnome-charac
loop13 squashf                                                /snap/core18/1074
loop14 squashf                                                /snap/gnome-3-26-1
loop15 squashf                                                /snap/vlc/1049
loop16 squashf                                                /snap/gnome-system
loop17 squashf                                                /snap/gnome-3-28-1
sda                                                           
├─sda1 vfat              4DD5-F9C6                            /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4              766c6a6f-98fc-4c26-868c-c2d542ad373a /
└─sda3 ext4              09724afe-6b53-4b29-afb8-0760ed0a1b01 /home
sdb                                                           
└─sdb1 ext4    The_Vault 41aed6f4-8336-48ef-95d0-9911d81e9f75 /mnt/vault
sr0
```

Comment: You may want autofs.  https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-configure-autofs-automount-linux/ & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs
use autofs for any storage that isn't connected directly to the system with SAS, SATA, eSATA, or Infiniband connections

Comment: @oldfred All the drives are connected via SATA.

Answer (score 0):

Change in /etc/fstab/

```
UUID=41aed6f4-8336-48ef-95d0-9911d81e9f75   /mnt/vault  ext4    defaults,nofail 0   2
```

to

```
UUID=41aed6f4-8336-48ef-95d0-9911d81e9f75   /mnt/vault  ext4  user,noauto,nofail 0   0
```

Option defaults means

rw, suid, dev, exec, **auto**, nouser and async

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `noauto` **prevent** the partition from being automatically mounted at boot time?
In my case, I want the partition to be mounted at boot time _if it is present_. If it is not present, I want the system to continue without it.
Also, why is the sixth parameter in the `fstab` entry changed from 0 to 2?

Comment: Forget my answer, I had wrong Partition in mind.  Any chance you wrote an own udev rule or systemd service?

Comment: No, I have not done either of those.

Comment: `sudo sudo lsblk -f`  please.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've updated the question.